# divison x86 assembly floating exception (core dump)

Tags: x86

I cannot use **div** operator in **x86** again after using it the first time. When I input number 106, 106 divided by 25. First, i move 25 into **%ebx** then use **div** and it worked fine. But when I move 5 into **%ebx** again then take the remainder 6 divided by 5, it says floating exception. Even though, I already move the remainder to **%eax**, i can't use div anymore

```
.data
   message:
           .ascii"Enter the number of cents: \0"
   quarter:
           .ascii" Quarter(s)\n\0"
   dime:
           .ascii" Dime(s)\n\0"
   nickel:
           .ascii" Nickel(s)\n\0"
   penny:
          .ascii" Penny(s)\n\0"

.text
.global _start
_start:

  mov $message, %eax         
  call PrintStringC
  call ScanInt



  mov $25, %ebx
  div %ebx               

  # print out change in Quarter
  call PrintInt
  mov $quarter, %eax
  call PrintStringC

  mov %edx, %eax          # move remainder to eax



   mov $5, %ebx          # move 5 to ebx
   div %ebx              # Cannot use div again.

   call PrintInt
   mov $dime, %eax
   call PrintStringC
```

Comment: Just the classic "didn't clear `edx`" again

Comment: how do i clear it?

Comment: `xor edx, edx`, `mov edx, 0`, whatever you want as long as it has the right result

Comment: @harold: the x86 tag wiki has a link to a decent dup-target for these DIV questions, in the FAQ section.